# How can I check if element is json object or json array in android?

Tags: android, json

i want to access AmenityCodes you can see in the image for 0 position Amenity Codes is Array but on 49 positiin is json object so how to chek this is object or json array 
[image]

[image]

> MyActivity.java

```
for(int r=0;r<results.length();r++)
{

    HashMap<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hotelrating=results.getJSONObject(r).get(TAG_STARRATING).toString();
    deeplink=results.getJSONObject(r).get(TAG_HOTELDEEPLINK).toString();

    JSONArray amenityarray=results.getJSONObject(r).getJSONArray(TAG_AMENITYCODES);

    Log.e("Amenitiescode","-->"+amenityarray);

}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do nor what you are asking

Comment: Please give me your complete JSON string

Comment: hey my json array with in json array problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
JSONArray amenityarray=results.getJSONArray(r);
```

With:

```
JSONArray amenityarray=results.getJSONObject(r).getJSONArray("AmenityCodes");
```

Comment: hey thanks but how to chek is jsonarray or jsonobject u can see in second image amenitycode is json object not json array so how to chek is json object or json array

Comment: In this case you can use results.getJSONObject(r).get("AmenityCodes") and then check with instanceof

Comment: but before this i want to chek if is jsonarray than JSONArray amenityarray=results.getJSONObject(r).getJSONArray("AmenityCodes");  is called or if json object than results.getJSONObject(r).get("AmenityCodes") is called so i want to chek in for loop amenitycodes is array or object

Comment: i mean: Object obj = results.getJSONObject(r).get("AmenityCodes");     if(ojc instanceof JSONArray) {....}                                        else if(obj instanceof JSONObject) {....}